# Laravel Array Output

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am perfoming a query in my controller and outputting the total cost on my view.

Heres my query:

```
 $stat = array(
            'TotalCost' => DB::table('ORD_DETAIL')
                        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(OD_QTYORD * OD_QTYUNIT * OD_COSTPRICE) as TotalCost'))
                        ->where('OD_ORDER_NUMBER',$id)->first()
            );
```

Heres my output:

```
{{ $stat['TotalCost'] }}
```

But I am getting the error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: 
>   F:\view.blade.php)

Comment: Try adding `get()` after `first()` - `...first()->get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the above error is because you're query is returning an `Object`.

To get around this you can either do:

```
{{ $stat['TotalCost']->TotalCost }}
```

Or you could change your query to use Laravel's built-in `sum()` method:

```
DB::table('ORD_DETAIL')
    ->where('OD_ORDER_NUMBER',$id)
    ->sum(DB::raw('OD_QTYORD * OD_QTYUNIT * OD_COSTPRICE'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
{{ $stat['TotalCost']->TotalCost }}
```

To maintain

```
{{ $stat['TotalCost'] }}
```

change your query to

```
 $stat = array(
        'TotalCost' => DB::table('ORD_DETAIL')
                    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(OD_QTYORD * OD_QTYUNIT * OD_COSTPRICE) as TotalCost'))
                    ->where('OD_ORDER_NUMBER',$id)->lists('TotalCost')->first();
        );
```